# How to create virtual machine environments?

Tags: virtualization

I want to create a number of virtual machine environments for testing new beta releases - Windows 7, VS2010, Windows Server 2008  and so on. My host OS is Windows XP. What is the best way of going about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you have no budget, use Virtual Box. I'm happily testing all the apps and O/S you mentioned in it on my home PC.

Comment: Another vote for VirtualBox. Just make sure you have adequate RAM and disk space.

Comment: Happy VirtualBox user here (linux host) - recommend it over any other "free" solution (including vmware server 2.x)

Answer (score 1):

depends on your budget. probably you'll end-up getting [vmware server](http://vmware.com/download/server/getserver.html).

if you can afford running additional box - consider installing there [esxi](http://www.vmware.com/products/esxi/).

in both cases - the more ram, the better.

Answer (score -1):

you try centos 5.3 with xen kernel

Comment: as the OP said, the host OS is Windows XP.
Also, Xen isn't exactly the best choice for running windows guests (though not impossible - it needs specific hardware support)